# joomla blank page front end issue

Tags: joomla1.5

My site is working fine on local wamp server but when I upload it on live server then its front end shows blank only where as admin section working fine.When I start debug it then I found my control is not goes beyond the line `$retval = $this->$doTask();` in controller.php of library folder under execute method.So please advise `$this->$doTask();` calls to which function as `$doTask` is variable contains 'display' string.

Comment: has the code been copied completelty to your new server?

Comment: yes I have did it two times mate,Actually I did not get the article contents display mate.But I am strange the same code is working fine on wamp server.

Comment: Which server are you uploading it to? Windows? Linux?

Comment: linux server@opensource-ios

Comment: Can you Try installing a plain Joomla version not your project and tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Actually when I enable the error reporting then Strict Standards: Non-static method JLoader::import() should not be called statically such type errors are shown only@opensource-ios

Comment: I think some of the files are not copied over to your server, or there could be some permission issues, Try to check permissions also